# rsync flock not deleting flocktmp.lock file?

Tags: linux, rsync, flock

Recently i changed my rsync flock command, and now it stopped deleting the flocktmp.lock file, when the sync is done. Can anyone see the error in my command? That would really help me out!

flock -xn /tmp/flocktmp.lock -c "/usr/bin/rsync -avz --perms --chmod=a+rwx --delete 'user@some.site.com:~/www/user.some.site.com/public_html/links/rtorrent_data/iRL\ REMUX/' /media/HDD01/shares/SB/iRL\ REMUX"

I tried deleting the flock file, and running the command again, but it never deletes the file after a sync.

Also i tried several different combinations, but i can't get it right.